# Having angular [ngClass] refresh classes dynamically (based on data updated in a service)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular-changedetection

I have a template with something like this:

```
<span [ngStyle]="{'color': s.isDetecting ? 'red' : 'green'}" class="right-icon">
    <i [ngClass]="s.isDetecting ? 'fas fa-eye' : 'fas fa-eye-slash'"></i>
    {{s.detectingStatus}}
</span>
```

In my component, I have basically this:

```
// ...
@Input() countSensor: PartyInfo = null;

s: DataInfo = null;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.s = this.countSensor.data;
}
```

Note: `countSensor` is passed from parents to children and is updated every few seconds in a service.

Now, with this code, the `[ngStyle]` works properly, the color changes when it should, same for the `{{s.detectingStatus}}` string interpolation.
However, the class doesn't seem to be updated with `[ngClass]`: The icon always stays the same.

How can I make my `[ngClass]` refresh the class and work dynamically as `[ngStyle]` does?

---

After some time researching here on SO and elsewhere, I've tried a few things :

Manually trigger the component change detection using the `detectChanges()` method from a `ChangeDetectorRef` passed to the constructor whenever my service updates my `countSensor`.

But this didn't change my behavior.

I also tried to use `async` in my template but I couldn't manage to do it since my `s.isDetecting` is not observable.
Is there a simple way to make an observable bound to that variable? That might be a solution...

Comment: What is the value s.isDetecting is containing? you just want to validate whether a property exists or not ?

Comment: If `countSensor` is in a service, you don't need to pass it from parents to children. Simply reference it directly from the service : `{{ theService.countSensor }}`. That's what services are for, they're singletons.

Comment: The thing is I have many `countSensor` in my service, and they are all displayed in a specific component.  I guess i could pass its `Id` instead, and then retrieve the proper `countSensor` from the service and see what happens. But my current sensor is actually already referencing to the sensor in the service. I think the issue here is moe likely tied to `ngClass` not refreshing the class the values are all updted correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Your value is coming as a Input, so watch it in ngOnchanges,

```
ngOnChanges(change:SimpleChange) {
  if(change.countSensor) {
    //put your logic here
  }
}
```